# Error starting twincat AdsError: device timeout

Tags: twincat

At one point in my TwinCAT 3 project I suddenly couldn't start my project in `<Local>` mode. I didn't pay much attention to it but now I need to get back to the project and the industrial computer is in production, I don't have access to it so I can't launch my app directly on it so I need to fix this error I get when I try to launch the app on my computer.

I get two pop-up errors windows when I click on the `Activate configuration` button.
First one states:

```
Error starting TwinCAT system!
Init12\IO: Set State TComObj SAFEOP: Set Objects (11) to SAFEOP >> AdsError: 1817 (0x719, ADS ERROR: device has a timeout)
For further information start the event viewer and open the log.
```

The second one states:

```
12/12/2022 15:30:00 573 ms | 'TwinCAT System' (10000): Sending ams command >> Init12\IO: Set State TComObj SAFEOP: Set Objects (11) to SAFEOP >> AdsError: 1817 (0x719, ADS ERROR: device has a timeout) << failed!
```

I disabled my IO card (which is an EtherCAT device), I also tried to disable the SafetyCard but I still get the problem.

I tried to run the `win8settick.bat` script and reboot multiples times, it didn't work.

`Hyper-V` is disabled.

I tried using `Visual Studio 2019` and `TwinCAT XAE Shell` directly (which runs under `Visual Studio 2017` I believe)

I have tried all these on my computer directly (Windows 10 64 bits 12 cores i7 CPU) and also on a `Windows 10 IoT Enterprise 2019 LTSC` virtual machine which has the same configuration as my industrial computer.

Does anyone know how I could solve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems related https://stackoverflow.com/q/71353168/6329629 :p

Comment: Did you disable all IO? Maybe it has something to do with it, see also [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf6311_tc3_tcpudp/1106587787.html?id=6910698405571959407).

Comment: @Roald ah I knew I had already asked that, well let me delete this old question with no answer since this one has more details

Comment: @Roald I only have one card which is called Device 2 (EtherCAT), I disabled it and the problem was still there. I also tried to clear All Mapping Info just out of despair and it didn't change anything. I have tried the [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tf6311_tc3_tcpudp/1106587787.html?id=6910698405571959407) . I don't have an Ethernet adapter (technically) so this doesn't really applies but I still tried to install my EtherNET card in the `compatible device` (just to try) and then apply `(none)` in Search for my EtherCAT device and the problem is still there..

Comment: Did you check event viewer if it has any more information? I would send that to the Beckhoff support and they might have a clue then.

Comment: @ziga Sadly it doesn't give much more information, it just repeats the error with less information in it..

Comment: Try contacting beckhoff support, I am very lucky to have a great team that responds in minutes, always solving the issues. I would suggest you give them a go ;)

Comment: @ziga so quick update I was left with no answer from Beckhoff support haha

Comment: what if you try and create a new project and just import the PLC? Try going step by step, I had issues where the files got corrupted (importing TC2 exports is buggy), for me it was a device description for EtherCAT master and its variables.

Comment: Are there updates regarding this topic?

Comment: @DonMiguelSanchez There's no promising update...

Comment: @Jack is it possible to get a version of you software to test? I am very curious about it

Answer (score 0):

If ADS is returning that error when an IP stack TcCOM object is started, the configuration of the network card is probably incorrect.

Check the settings under “Adapter” for the network card in the project folder.

The configuration of the network card for the TCP/UDP RT module is documented in more detail here:

https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6311_tc3_tcpudp/1106587787.html&id=

Hope it works!!

Comment: Hello, I have seen this article but I don't have any Ethernet adapter in my devices, only an EtherCAT device so I can't configure the card as it is not there on my computer. I also have disabled this card so it shouldn't return an error...

Answer (score 0):

This message basically says that one of the TcCom-Objects did not start up correctly.
Almost everything is a TcCom-Object in TC3. EC-Master, EC-Slave, PLC, Axis, XTS-Mover, Task, C++ Modules, ... In your case the TcSystem-Object failed to switch to SafeOp. This can have a bunch of reasons. Saying, you have to provide more information. Please give use a screenshot of your project tree and have a look in the (Windows-)Event-Viewer on the target system. Also the Output-Window in the IDE can provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar problems / errors and for me the following procedure always works:

[image: Reload TM/TMC Descriptions]

It happens sometimes when you work in an IPC and after that you want to continue working in another machine, it seems `Twincat` make diverse configurations with the TcCom objects that are not migrated when you archive the solution, you can give it a try, I hope it helps